# How to prevent WSEACCESS error on Send via raw socket on Windows XP SP3 for normal user accounts

Tags: windows-xp, socket, permissions

I have recently begun trying to run our company apps under normal windows user accounts rather than under an account with Administrators group membership.  Several of these are failing when atempting to send data on a raw socket (specifically this is an Indy ICMP implementaiton, we are using to ping another server).

Under an account with Administrators membershipt this works just fine.  Try it without and the Send() on the raw socket fails with WSEACCESS.

Operating system XP Pro SP3 + hot fixes.

Any ideas how to rectify this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm don't think this is possible. Raw Sockets functionality is only available to members of the Administrators Group. (See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740548(VS.85).aspx).)

There's a [similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282783/raw-sockets-privilege-for-normal-user) that has an answer for server 2003, but as the poster suggests, it probably isn't supported in XP.

Comment: Seems to work fine with XP SP3